# Choosing between derived classes and adding an additional property in entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have the following `StudentGroup` class:

```
public class StudentGroup
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    //the set of peers who will review the work of the StudentGroup
    [ForeignKey("PeerReviewGroupId")]
    public PeerReviewGroup PeerReviewGroup { get; set; }
    public int? PeerReviewGroupId { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<GroupMembership> GroupMemberships { get; set; }
}
```

Derived from this class is `PeerReviewGroup`, in which there are two new properties:

```
public class PeerReviewGroup: StudentGroup
{
    [ForeignKey("StudentToReview")]
    public ApplicationUser StudentToReview { get; set; }
    public string StudentToReviewId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("StudentGroupToReview")]
    public StudentGroup StudentGroupToReview { get; set; }
    public string StudentGroupToReviewId { get; set; }

}
```

`PeerReviewGroup` could be assigned to an individual (i.e., `StudentToReview`) or another group (i.e., `StudentrGoup`). So, either of these values has to be `null`.

Instead, I could drive two classes:

```
public class PeerReviewGroupForIndividuals: StudentGroup
{
    [ForeignKey("StudentToReview")]
    public ApplicationUser StudentToReview { get; set; }
    public string StudentToReviewId { get; set; }
}

public class PeerReviewGroupForGroups: StudentGroup
{
    [ForeignKey("StudentGroupToReview")]
    public StudentGroup StudentGroupToReview { get; set; }
    public string StudentGroupToReviewId { get; set; }

}
```

I wonder if this is preferable or not, or which approach is the best practice. I think deriving two classes complicates things. Any suggestions?

Comment: So you have two groups of students and one group can review the other group?

Comment: @ShaiCohen yes, but the `PeerReviewGroup` can also review a student. It does not have to be a `StudentGroup`.

Comment: This is usually a tradeoff between normalization/less redundancy and simplicity. It depends on the context what is more important in the specific case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel you ***may*** be over-complicating the problem.

Why would the following approach not work:

```
public class StudentGroup
{
    [Key]
    public int Id {get; set;}

    //the students who comprise the group
    //the list can contain 1 to n users
    public List<ApplicationUser> Members
}

public class PeerReviewSession
{
    //this is the group of students who are performing the review
    [ForeignKey("GroupReviewing")]
    public StudentGroup GroupReviewing {get; set;}

    //this is the group of students who are being reviewed
    [ForeignKey("GroupReviewed")]
    public StudentGroup GroupReviewed {get; set;}

}
```

There may be some elements missing here, since I do not know the entire scenario. However, if your basic premise is as I suggested in the comments:

> "you have two groups of students and one group can review the other group"

Then this is really all you need.

Answer (score 1):

> `PeerReviewGroup` could be assigned to an individual (i.e., `StudentToReview`) or another group (i.e., `StudentGroup`). So, either of these values has to be `null`.
>
> Instead, I could drive two classes

At face value, your interpretation is correct. Since you never need both properties at the same time, there is no purpose to putting them in the same entity/table.

However, it seems reasonably possible that a given (existing) peer review group can be assigned to a student today, and to a student group tomorrow. If you split the entities, that means that you have to recreate your peer review group every time they switch being assigned to a student or a group.

I don't know enough about your application to make that call.

- If a peer review group is a persistent entity that survives multiple assignments over time, then you either keep the properties together or look for a more abstracted structure (see my suggestion below)
- If a peer review group is a discardable entity which you recreate every time a new  assignment is made, then you can favor splitting the entities using inheritance.

Entity inheritance is a really powerful tool that can help with keeping things sane; but as always, overapplying inheritance leads to insanity down the line.

---

**Alternate suggestion**

Another approach to this can be to not derive the peer review group, but rather provide a base class between student and student groups. Something along the lines of:

```
public abstract class PeerReviewSubject
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
}

public class Student : PeerReviewSubject { }

public class StudentGroup : PeerReviewSubject { }

public class PeerReviewGroup : StudentGroup
{
    [ForeignKey("Subject")]
    public PeerReviewSubject Subject { get; set; }
    public string SubjectId { get; set; }
}
```

*I don't like the `string` IDs you're using, but that's a different battle.*

This achieves the same result, but it won't require you to keep extending `PeerReviewGroup` whenever a new peer-reviewable entity type is added to the domain. Instead, every new peer reviewable entity type simply derives from `PeerReviewSubject` and can therefore be assigned to a peer review group.

I made `PeerReviewSubject` abstract in the example. That's not required, but it is the way to go if you don't want to create barebones `PeerReviewSubject` objects without further derivation.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response! Very much appreciated. The `PeerReviewGroup` and `StudentGroup` will be specific to an assignment and they will not persist afterwards. Also, if `PeerReviewGroup` is assigned to a `StudentGroup` (or `Student`), it will not change later (to a `Student` or to a different `StudentGroup`. Based on this information, do you think I should go for Inheritance or not?

Comment: @renakre: I personally think my alternate suggestion is a better approach to entity inheritance for your particular use case, but both approaches will get you to where you're trying to go.

Answer (score 1):

To answer this question, you need to think about the lifecycle of your `PeerReviewGroup`:

- is it ALWAYS known at its creation what kind of group it is ?
- is it ABSOLUTELY excluded that the same group changes its kind of review subject once it is created ?

If the answer is yes to both questions, you could consider making two classes. But this does not necessarily mean that you should.

A more fundamental question is whether a `PeerReviewGroupforIndividuals` **IS-A** really specific `PeerReviewGroup` very different from the others (inheritance) or if it is just a `PeerReviewGroup` that just **HAS-A** different `Subject` to study (composition).  After all, nothing looks closer to a peer review reviewing a group than a peer review group reviewing an individual. The same group could even do both.

The frontier between the two alternatives can be somewhat fuzzy. In case of doubt:

> Prefer [composition over inheritance](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)